# React Native why does the app crash when sending photo to API

Tags: javascript, react-native

My app keeps crashing when user tries to send photo from camera to API. There were no problem in the android emulator but it crashes on my physical device (Galaxy A30). The console.log doesn't show anything when I used it on the emulator. There were no problem submitting from image gallery but when submitting from the camera, it crashes.

```js
import React, {useState, useContext} from 'react';
import {ScrollView, View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Alert} from 'react-native';
import { AuthContext } from '../Context/AuthContext';
import { URLs } from '../constants/links';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";
import { CAMERA } from "expo-permissions";

const MyScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    const { myToken } = useContext(AuthContext)
    const [allImage, setAllImage] = React.useState([]);
    const [pickedImage, setPickedImage] = useState("");
    const [fileName, setFileName] = React.useState(""); 
    const formdata = new FormData();
    
    const cameraPermission = async () => {
      const result = await Permissions.askAsync(CAMERA);
      if (result.status != "granted") {
        Alert.alert(
          "Insufficient Permission",
          "You need to grant camera permission to use this app",
          [{ text: "Okay" }]
        );
        return true;
      }
      return true;
    };
    
    const useCamera = async () => {
        const hasPermissions = await cameraPermission();
        if (!hasPermissions) {
            return;
        }
        if(allImage.length < 4){
            let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
                allowsEditing: true,
                quality: 0.5,
            });

            if (!result.cancelled) { 
                const name = result.uri.split('/').pop();
                let match = /\.(\w+)$/.exec(name);
                let type = match ? `image/${match[1]}` : `image`;
                let newFile = {
                    uri: result.uri,
                    type: type,
                    name: name
                }
                setAllImage(newFile)
                setPickedImage(result.uri)
                if (!pickedImage && allImage.length === 0) {
                    setAllImage([newFile]); 
                    setFileName("Photo 1")
                }else {
                    setAllImage([...allImage, newFile]); 
                    setFileName(fileName + ", Photo " + (allImage.length + 1))  
                }
            }
        } else  { 
            Alert.alert("Image", "You have reach the image upload limit");
        }
    };

    const fetchData = () => {
        const abortCont = new AbortController(); 
        allImage.forEach((file) => {
            formdata.append('files[]', file);
        });
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: URLs,
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                Authorization: myToken,
                'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data", 
            },
            data: formdata,
            signal: abortCont.signal,
        }).then(function (result) { 
            if(result.data.message === "Successfully added") {
                Alert.alert("Upload Successufull", result.data.message);
                navigation.goBack()
            }

        }).catch(function (error) { 
            Alert.alert("Error", error); 
            formdata = new FormData();
        });
        
        return () => abortCont.abort();
    }
 

    return (
        <ScrollView>
            <View>
                <View>
                    <Text>Attach Receipt File</Text>
                    <View>
                        <TextInput 
                            editable={false}
                            placeholder="Select files.."
                            value={fileName}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} onPress={useCamera}>
                            <Text>Camera</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>

                    <View>
                        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.9} onPress={fetchData}>
                            <Text>Submit</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
}

export default MyScreen;
```

Comment: You never define `formData`

Comment: @Phil thats not the problem. It works fine before I set the permission

Comment: Sorry, no. That's not how JavaScript works. This will be throwing an error like _"Uncaught ReferenceError: formData is not defined"_

Comment: @Phil Its define already. I didn't put the whole code here because the code will be too long to submit here.

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Others should be able to take your code, run it themselves and hit the same problem you are seeing, not some other problem due to missing pieces

Comment: @Phil I edited the post. Hope this is sufficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know the reason why the app crash when user send photo taken from camera but I found a solution. I change from using camera from expo-permission to Camera from expo-camera. This is the docs: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#cameracapturedpicture